# Fontello to Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, fontello

I am using a Wordpress Theme (Avada) which has fontawesome icons pre-installed. My customer wants to use lineicons from http://fontello.com/! He downloaded the .zip file and sent it to me. Here is what I did:

1) Unpacked -zip file and got the following files:
- css folder
- font folder
- config.json
- demo.html
- README.txt

2) I uploaded everything inside the CSS folder to: /wp-content/themes/Avada/css

3) I uploaded everything inside the font folder to: /wp-content/themes/Avada/fonts/fontello/

4) Now I opened up /wp-content/themes/Avada/css/fpslineicons.css and set the @font-face to the following paths:

```html
@font-face {
  font-family: 'fpslineicons';
  src: url('../fonts/fontello/fpslineicons.eot?98281823');
  src: url('../fonts/fontello/fpslineicons.eot?98281823#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/fontello/fpslineicons.woff?98281823') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/fontello/fpslineicons.ttf?98281823') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/fontello/fpslineicons.svg?98281823#fpslineicons') format('svg');
```

After that I went to my admin panel and enterd in text modus on my frontpage the following code:

```
<i class="icon-heart">Test</i>
```

I also tried:

```
<div class="icon-heart">Test</div>
```

Guess what? Nothing is displayed. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I cannot find what is wrong.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting explicitly the `font-family` for your `<i>` and `<div>` to `fontello`

```
div {font-family:'fontello'}
```

since you are already using another icon fonts library this can be the issue

Comment: That does not helped! I added your code to style.css but nothing changed. Still no icons visible on my website. Any other idea?

Comment: I don't know how your css code is structured. You might have rules that overwrite this, try to do that on the Dec tools and check first

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `@font-face{font-family: "fontello";}` and `[class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before {font-family: "fontello";}` are the same.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'fontello';
  src: url('../fonts/fontello/fpslineicons.eot?98281823');
  src: url('../fonts/fontello/fpslineicons.eot?98281823#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/fontello/fpslineicons.woff?98281823') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/fontello/fpslineicons.ttf?98281823') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/fontello/fpslineicons.svg?98281823#fpslineicons') format('svg');
}
```